# Is it possible to cast a FxCop.SDK.TypeNode to a System.Type

Tags: fxcop

Is it possible to cast a FxCop.SDK.TypeNode in Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk to an System.Type ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  There used to be a reflection "bridge" built into FxCop for this, but [it was removed in FxCop 1.36](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2007/02/25/framework-for-intergrated-fxcop-rule-testing.aspx).  You could potentially roll your own mechanism based on the assembly location and the type name.  However, this really shouldn't be necessary in most cases.  If you could explain why you want to do this, it might be possible to suggest an alternate approach...

Comment: I'm trying to load and read the assembly without locking it. I need to read classes that are in a specific namespace and need to use the Type object of those classes. I will be doing this from a T4 template. I been using the VolatileAssembly, but this only runs 1-time, after that it says could not find namespace are you missing a references.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the Type object of those classes"?  Do you need to run code from those classes or read metadata from the types?  If the latter, you can do this via the FxCop APIs.  If you're not sure how, please post the code you would write against the Type if you could get it.

Comment: if i have a namespace of : "Bob.entities" and have a class of Bob.entities.myclass1 , i want to get bob.entities.myclass1 in a type object. Basicly i just need to read an assemlby from a t4 template. It works normally but if i do .... Bob.Some and have an ohter assembly of Bob.Some.Extended , that uses Bob.Some , i get an error saying assembly not referenced ... i only runs 1-time then i get that error.... just doesn't make sense. I don't remember the exact code... since im on vacation now... but its something like ... Assembly.GetTypes() where assembly name = Bob.Entites

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to do with that Type once you've got it?

Comment: I want to use functions like : Type.GetFields() . And generate something based on those values.

Comment: Why do you need to do this via Type when you already have an FxCop TyeNode?  For example, you can get the fields from the members collection returned by the TypeNode.Members property (e.g.: yourTypeNode.Members.Where(m => m.NodeType == NodeType.Field).Cast<Field>()).

Comment: i have this code: "foreach(Type t in assembly.getTypes() { generator1.Generate(t); generator2.Generate(t); } ... So that is why i want the whole type. But i'll try your suggestion, thanks.